# How to get sorted results in powershell using az storage entity query?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-cli

When you are using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) you can click on the name of each columns to sort the results by that field.
[image: In Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer you can sort results]
Is there any way to sort query results in PowerShell using `az storage entity query`?
In another word, I can get the results in Azure CLI as an object and I can sort it using `Sort-Object`, but I want to sort entries on the Azure Storage Server and get `sorted-results`. It's not useful to get all of the data from the server and sort it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Operators-Supported-for-the-Table-Service?redirectedfrom=MSDN.

There's a complete list of supported operators you can use with Azure Storage Table, `OrderBy` is sadly not among the supported ones.

This means, you will need to retrieve the data first, then do the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want to sort entries on the Azure Storage Server and get
>   sorted-results. It's not useful to get all of the data from the server
>   and sort it manually.

It is not possible as Azure Tables does not support server-side sorting. You will need to fetch the desired data on the client and perform the sorting there only.